# How to get Blaze (the standalone portion of Meteor's template engine) to use a dynamically downloaded template

Tags: javascript, templates, dynamic, meteor-blaze, single-page-application

I am using the standalone blaze for dynamically rendered templates.  I love most of it so far, its ability to quickly do fine grained dom updates is great.

Where I'm coming up short is how to handle the situation where I have downloaded a template via ajax and need to get blaze to parse it so I can inject it into my front end.

My reason for doing this is that I don't want the templates for portions of my SPA that require authentication to be downloaded until an appropriate user logs in.  Admin pages for example would never be downloaded for general users.

Don't bother telling me I'm doing security wrong, I already am using a zero trust model with every API request, but what I WANT is a zero trust model the other way as well, if you're not authenticated, you don't even get to see the template.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across a possible alternative solution by coming at the problem a bit sideways.

My issue is that I don't want say admin pages and other templates to be visible within the dom inspectors.  I'd rather not load them at all, but I have yet to solve that level.

What I did discover however is that once Blaze loads the templates, you can remove the actual template code from the dom and blaze will still render them correctly.

This at least allows me to obfuscate that stuff away a bit.  An enterprising hacker will still be able to  get those templates by monitoring network traffic, but at least they're not out in the open.

Proper security using this method still requires that client code be minified and obfuscated, preferably protected somewhat by ACL on the server, and calling into an API that uses some form of ACL verification.